# How to have CCK "Select list" field on my content type?

Tags: entities

I want to include in my content type a CCK "Select List" field.
Which module(s) should I enable so as to have it as a choice?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to enabled Option Widgets, as well as Number and/or Text.
[image: Required modules for question 7615]

Create a new field by going to admin/content/node-type/%content-type%/fields  *(where %content-type% is the machine name of your content type)*

Create a new field.  If you enabled Text module, you have the option of Text.  If you enabled Number, then you have the option of Decimal, Float and Integer.

[image: question 7615 field types]

Select the Operations you want

[image: question 7615 field operations]

Clicking Save will take to the Field setting page. Scroll down to the bottom and type in the allow values for your option widget.

[image: question 7615 field settings - allowed values]

And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

CCK is the module you need - turn on *Options Widget* in your modules list under the CCK category.  If you're using Drupal 6, the configuration should look like [image]

If you're using Drupal 7, it should be even more straight forward as it's one of the options presented in the Field Type.

Comment: Yes,but when I choose "Text" I have not the "Select list" option.Only the Text and Text are options.Should I enable any extra modules?

Comment: Check to see that you have CCK:Option Widgets enabled.

Comment: Which one widget should I enable?

Comment: The name is `Option Widgets` in your modules list