# How can I map multiple fields to one 'parent' field?

Tags: entities

What I want to do is best illustrated with an example.

Apartments have different price ranges for different units according to how many bedrooms/bathrooms those units have.

How could I set up a content type that will allow me to do something like this:

$500 -- 5br/4ba

$400 -- 4br/3ba

$350 -- 4br/2ba

In the above example each price range has a corresponding 'bedroom' and 'bathroom' value.
In order for this to work I need to map these price ranges to these values. Each apartment entity can have up to 10 of these mapping pairs.

I hope this makes sense. I can't figure out how to set up the content type.

Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0):

See this example post on Select lists for content types:
[How to have CCK "Select list" field on my content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7615/how-to-have-cck-select-list-field-on-my-content-type)

you would just make the values for the list option as (`value | display text`):

```
500 | $500 - 5br/4ba
400 | $400 - 4br/3ba
350 | $350 - 4br/2ba
... 6 more options of whatever conditions ...
 25 | $25 - you sleep in the closet
```

This price field could allow up to 10 values if that's your limit.

Since the keys (values) of the prices are integers. You could SUM or Aggregate the values using Views if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)?

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>   When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.

With this module, I think that you could create a scheme whereby the field containing the bed/bath values would be dependent on the field containing the price values. Selecting $500 (for example) would automatically update the bed/bath value for the node with '5br/4ba'. Not entirely sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Not quite what I need. I installed it and played around with it. But it doesn't map my values. I need something that takes a price, asks the user how many BR, BA are associated with that price, and then associates that price with those values.

Comment: I don't follow. You should probably clarify your issue in the OP.